# Grouping few columns of JSON array Newtonsoft c#

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have a JSON structure like this

```
{
  "Success": true,
  "Errors": [],
  "Warnings": [],
  "PageNumber": 1,
  "RecordsPerPage": 1000,
  "TotalPages": 2,
  "TotalRecords": 1555,
  "Data": [
    {
      "Project Code": "P4533",
      "Project Name": "Test Project",
      "November 2020": "200.00",
      "October 2020": "600.00",
      "July 2020": "100.00",
      "June 2020": "30.00",
      "February 2020": "550.00",
      "April 2020": "90.00",
      "August 2020": "50.00",
      "December 2020": "110.00",
      "September 2020": "80.00",
      "January 2020": "1000.00",
      "May 2020": "250.00",
      "March 2020": "80.00",
      "Total": "0.00"
    },
    {
      "Project Code": "P3456",
      "Project Name": "P1",
      "November 2020": "270.00",
      "October 2020": "900.00",
      "July 2020": "80.00",
      "June 2020": "40.00",
      "February 2020": "1000.00",
      "April 2020": "70.00",
      "August 2020": "500.00",
      "December 2020": "20.00",
      "September 2020": "450.00",
      "January 2020": "200.00",
      "May 2020": "300.00",
      "March 2020": "500.00",
      "Total": "0.00"
    }
]
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft to Deserialize the above into an Class with a different structure. So its not having data for each of the month. I need to group each of the quarter and sum corresponding column for that. Then assign that to my class object.

Straight deserializing I am doing by

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<project>(myjson);
```

But how can I manipulate the data to get a quarterwise data. Is there is any LINQ way for that??

Output data could be something like this

```
{
      "Success": true,
      "Errors": [],
      "Warnings": [],
      "PageNumber": 1,
      "RecordsPerPage": 1000,
      "TotalPages": 2,
      "TotalRecords": 1555,
      "Data": [
        {

          "Project Code": "P4533",
          "Project Name": "Test Project",
          "Q1" : 1630,
          "Q2" : 370,
          "Q3" : 230,
          "Q4" : 910,
          "Total" :3160
        },
        {
          "Project Code": "P3456",
          "Project Name": "P1",
          "Q1" : 1700
          "Q2" : 410
          "Q3" : 1030
          "Q4" : 1190
          "Total" : 4630
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how my class looks like

```
public class KipProjects
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public ProjectData[] Data { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Data")]
    public ForecastData Data2 { get; set; }


}
public class ForecastData
{
    public string Quarter1 { get; set; }
    public string Quarter2 { get; set; }
    public string Quarter3 { get; set; }
    public string Quarter4 { get; set; }
    public string  Total { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your C# class that you're deserializing into?

Answer (score 1):

Writing LINQ is probably doable, but I lean to think it will likely become way too complicated to maintain. I would instead suggest writing a custom [CustomJsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for your `Data` property:

```cs
class ForecastDataConverter : JsonConverter<ForecastData>
{
    public override ForecastData ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, ForecastData existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {       
        var keys = JObject.Load(reader).Children().Cast<JProperty>().ToList(); // read everything

        var fixedProps = keys.Where(k => k.Name == "Project Code" || k.Name == "Project Name" || k.Name == "Total").ToList(); // pick fields we don't want to roll-up quarterly 
        var dataProps = keys.Except(fixedProps); // pick fields we want to massage further

        var reconstructed = new JObject(fixedProps); // target JObject here

        var total = 0.0; // keep track of totals 
        // parse each key name into DateTime for grouping into quarterly buckets
        foreach (var quarter in dataProps.GroupBy(d => (DateTime.ParseExact(d.Name, "MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month - 1) / 3)) //credit for this grouping technique goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8089289/12339804
        {           
            var quarterValue = quarter.Sum(gg => double.Parse(gg.Value.ToString())); 
            reconstructed.Add($"Quarter{quarter.Key+1}", quarterValue);         
            total+=quarterValue; // totals
        }

        reconstructed.Remove("Total"); // we had this field in source but it seems to be empty. so you have an option to populate it here. otherwise just chuck all related calculations from above
        reconstructed.Add("Total", total);

        var target = new ForecastData(); // make new instance
        serializer.Populate(reconstructed.CreateReader(), target);// Populate the object properties

        return target;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, ForecastData value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // we don't need it
    }
}
public class KipProjects
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public ProjectData[] Data { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Data")]
    public List<ForecastData> Data2 { get; set; }
}
public class ForecastData
{
    public string Quarter1 { get; set; }
    public string Quarter2 { get; set; }
    public string Quarter3 { get; set; }
    public string Quarter4 { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
}
```

then you would be able to deserialise the whole thing by just calling your `JsonConvert` like so:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KipProjects>(yourData, new ForecastDataConverter());
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you know how to Serialize and Deserialize data to and from JSON format. So what you want to know:

> Given as input an enumerable sequence of `Projects`, make a method that converts this into a sequence of `KipProjects`

You want this in a LINQ-like fashion. For this we create extension methods for `IEnumerable<Project>`. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

First we write a procedure to convert a Project into ForeCastData

I am not sure what's the benefit of having string properties, doing calculations is much easier when using the correct type. If your Project class doesn't have properties, you should write code to convert them to doubles

```
public class ForecastData
{
    public double Q1 {get; set;}
    public double Q2 {get; set;}
    public double Q3 {get; set;}
    public double Q4 {get; set;}       
    public double Total => Quarter.Sum();
}

public static ForeCastData ToForeCastData(this Project project)
{
     // TODO: decide what to do if project null
     return new ForecastData()
     {
         Q1 = project.January + project.February + project.March,
         Q2 = project.April + project.May + project.June,
         Q3 = project.July + project.August + project.September,
         Q4 = project.October + project.November + project.December,
     }
}
```

This shows that it was not a wise Idea to give the months in class Project a name instead of an index. It would have been much easier if the months were numbered 0..11

Alas you forget to tell us where you get the values for KipProjects.Success, TotalRecords, ProjectData. You'll have to fill them yourself

```
public static IEnumerable<KipProject> ToKipProjects(this IEnumerable<Project> projects)
{
    // TODO: handle projects == null
    return projects.Select(project => new KipProject
    {
        Succes = ???,
        ...

        Data2 = project.ToForecastData(),
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Project> projects = ReadJsonProjectData();
IEnumerable<KipProject> kipProjects = projects.ToKipProjects();
WriteJson(kipProjects);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.. Btw sorry I missed to mention success,errors, warning etc.. Those are all coming from an API call which is honestly I am not using. I just using the data array from that JSON